# Usage of MockK's matcher any() instead of object type makes my unit test work. Why?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, mockk, turbine

I have the following unit testing class that tests if a flow comes alright from the usecase.

This test is passing as I want. The thing is that when I use normal parameters instead of `any()` in the usecase invoke method the test doesn't pass. The flow `weeklyWeatherUiState` is not being updated. Check the comment.

```kotlin
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class QuestionUnitTest {
    @get:Rule
    var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    
    @MockK private lateinit var getCurrentWeatherUseCase: GetCurrentWeatherUseCase
    @RelaxedMockK private lateinit var isImperialUseCase: IsImperialUseCase
    @RelaxedMockK private lateinit var updateUnitMeasureUseCase: UpdateUnitMeasureUseCase

    private lateinit var viewModel: WeatherViewModel
    
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
        Dispatchers.setMain(StandardTestDispatcher())

        viewModel = WeatherViewModel(
            getCurrentWeatherUseCase,
            isImperialUseCase,
            updateUnitMeasureUseCase
        )
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun `Question about any() matcher`() = runTest {
        coEvery {
            getCurrentWeatherUseCase.invoke(
                city = any(),
                isImperial = any(),
                startDate = any()
            )

//          using the bellow instead of above, the code fails the test
//          getCurrentWeatherUseCase.invoke(
//              city = City("Sao Paulo"),
//              isImperial = false,
//              startDate = "2024-02-22"
//          )
        } returns flowOf(DataResponse.Success(listOf(Weather())))

        viewModel.getWeeklyWeather(City("Sao Paulo"))

        viewModel.weeklyWeatherUiState.test {
            awaitItem() // UiState.Loading
            val response = awaitItem()

            assertTrue(response is UiState.Success)
            cancelAndIgnoreRemainingEvents()
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel is like this:

```kotlin
    private val _weeklyWeatherUiState = MutableStateFlow<UiState<List<Weather>>>(UiState.Loading)
    val weeklyWeatherUiState: StateFlow<UiState<List<Weather>>> get() = _weeklyWeatherUiState

    fun getWeeklyWeather(city: City) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getWeatherUseCase.invoke(city, isImperial(), getTodaysDate()).collect {
                when (it) {
                    is DataResponse.Success -> {
                        _weeklyWeatherUiState.value = UiState.Success(it.data)
                    }
                    is DataResponse.Error -> {
                        _weeklyWeatherUiState.value = UiState.Error(it.message)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> **Why using the any() mockK's argument matcher works and using the expected objects doesn't?**

I'm using [MockK](https://mockk.io/) + [Turbine](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine) to test the flows.

Comment: I believe you need to set your coEvery with same data as you pass in viewModel.getWeeklyWeather(City("Sao Paulo")). if City is a class, then you have two different instances, unless you use data class for City.

Comment: @Umit I was trying the way you commented but without success. I only got success when started using `any()`. I had a constant `CITY` using the same `City` object for both calls you mentioned.

Comment: At first glance, it should be working without any issues, did you debug it - at which point it stops working?

What's the implementation of isImperial(), getTodaysDate() functions? Do parameters of the use case support nulls (bc any() also matches nulls)? Also if the flow is not emitting anything, could be that it crashes/not completes itself?